# Incremental increase of a record in XML

Tags: xml, vba

I found a code that exports a selected range (table) to an xml format using table headers. But I want to adapt this code.

See the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgZPV.png), each time I would like to increment my "Row_number" with 1. See the VBA code below. Can someone help me adapting this code? The code is from this [website](http://www.professionalexcel.com/2014/04/export-excel-table-range-to-xml-using-vba/).

```
Public Sub ExportRangeToXML()

Dim strXML As String
Dim varTable As Variant
Dim intRow As Integer
Dim intCol As Integer
Dim intFileNum As Integer
Dim strFilePath As String
Dim strRowElementName As String
Dim strTableElementName As String
Dim varColumnHeaders As Variant

    'Set custom names
    strTableElementName = "Table"
    strRowElementName = "Row_number"

    'Set file path
    strFilePath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(, "(*.xml),*.xml", , "Save As...")
    If strFilePath = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

    'Get table data
    varTable = Selection.Value
    varColumnHeaders = Selection.Rows(1).Value

    'Build xml
    strXML = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>"
    strXML = strXML & "<" & strTableElementName & ">"
    For intRow = 2 To UBound(varTable, 1)
        strXML = strXML & "<" & strRowElementName & ">"
        For intCol = 1 To UBound(varTable, 2)
            strXML = strXML & "<" & varColumnHeaders(1, intCol) & ">" & _
                varTable(intRow, intCol) & "</" & varColumnHeaders(1, intCol) & ">"
        Next
        strXML = strXML & "</" & strRowElementName & ">"
    Next
    strXML = strXML & "</" & strTableElementName & ">"

    'Get next file number
    intFileNum = FreeFile

    'Open the file, write output, then close file
    Open strFilePath For Output As #intFileNum
    Print #intFileNum, strXML
    Close #intFileNum

End Sub
```